# Why can't I use GregorianCalendar as an object type as a constructor parameter?

Tags: java, constructor, syntax-error

Why can't I use GregorianCalendar as an object type as a constructor parameter?

```
public class P(GregorianCalendar date){
```

Why can't I do this?

The error it give me is "syntax error on token "class", char expected".

Comment: That's a *class* declaration, not a *constructor* declaration. A constructor would be `public P(GregorianCalendar date)` - within a `public class P { ... }` class declaration.

Comment: And you should really avoid using this obsolete, badly designed class. Use classes of the java.time package. And while you're at it, use a meanungful name for your own class.

Comment: @JBNizet I need a type that stores dates

Comment: And there are several ones in the java.time package, all much better designed than GregorianCalendar, and suitable for various use-cases.

Comment: @JBNizet I get the same error with "Date date"

Comment: @user10610048 Read Jon Skeet's comment, carefully. That is the answer to your problem. Once you fixed your problem, following Jon's advice (you literally just have to copy and paste code), then read my comments, carefully. Date is **not** part of the java.time package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jon Skeet mentioned in the comments. Here is how you create a class with construtor that has one parameter

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class P {
   private LocalDate date;
   public P(LocalDate date){
      this.date = date;
   }
}
```

Comment: Correct and complete answer. Upvoted for using the modern `LocalDate` instead of the complex, poorly designed and long outdated `Calendar`.